# How to implement this scenario in wpf

Tags: wpf

I'm allowing two instance of wpf application

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length == 1)
        {    
            var w1 = new MainWindow("1");
            w1.Show();
        }
        else if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length == 2)
        {
           var w2 = new MainWindow("2");
            w2.Show();
        }
    }
```

Each window having different user setting like below
In Settings.setting

```
window1_city="xxx",window1_country="yyy"
window2_city="aaa",window2_country="bbb" .....etc
```

I want to apply the above settings on windows load(in constructor).
My current code is

```
 public MainWindow(string window)
 {
   if(window=="1")
      {
        lbl.Content=setting.window1_city
      }
    if(window=="2")
      {
        lbl.Content=setting.window2_city
      }
 }and so
```

But this is very difficult to apply if no.of user settings more. If user made any changes then I've to save those values according to window. So I've to use more no.of if loops.
Is there any other way to implement this?

Comment: Is setting variable of Specific Type ? and also You want these setting to be set only first time or dynamically like if change is done it should be reflected on UI?

Comment: yes. need to display dynamically in UI

Comment: Can you notify the properties of setting. like if window1_city changes can you notify that. If you can thn I think you can achieve this using conditional Binding.

Answer (score 0):

Use each window `DataContext` property to pass an object with all property needed, pass that object in the `Startup`, before `Show`.
Maybe you would better use some MVVM toolkit, if the app is going to be more complex.
An example in using plain DataContextes:

```
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        Process thisProc = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length == 1)
        {    
            var w1 = new MainWindow("1");
            var a = new MySettings();
            a.x=...;
            a.y=....;
            w1.DataContext=a;
            w1.Show();
        }
        else if (Process.GetProcessesByName(thisProc.ProcessName).Length == 2)
        {
           var w2 = new MainWindow("2");
           var b = new MySettings();
            b.x=...;
            b.y=....;
            w2.DataContext=b;
            w2.Show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide simple example for my scenario using DataContext